# Error: `brew cask` Is No Longer When "brew cask install iterm2" Command Is Run

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh, iterm2

I want to configure my `macOs` terminal with `zsh`. After installing `homebrew`, when I am trying to install `iterm2` running this command `brew cask install iterm2`, the error shows as like below:

**Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.**

May anyone suggest to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following command should solve your problem

`brew install --cask iterm2`